# macOS Sonoma 14.1.2 Finder cannot search files by name in external hard disk

Tags: finder, search, sonoma

In macOS Sonoma 14.1.2, the Finder cannot search files by part of the file names in some folders, e.g. external harddisk.

For example, the folder contains the following files:

- 539366.jpg
- 456.jpg
- 789.jpg

and I search "5393" in the Search box in the Finder in that particular folder (in a USB connected external drive), nothing shows up. But for other files not on the external hard drive, the search results are normal.

How can I fix this behavior? Looks like the external HDD is not indexed by the search?